# How to exclude negative values in resul

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please how can I get this query to exclude negative (-) values

```
SELECT Enrollment.Participant_ID
    ,Enrollment.Site
    ,Enrollment.ActualDelivery
    ,Forms.[2MonthQoL]
    ,[Enrollment].[ActualDelivery] + 70 AS Due
    ,DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ()) AS DaysOverdue
FROM Enrollment
LEFT JOIN Forms ON Enrollment.Participant_ID = Forms.Participant_IDFK
WHERE (
        ((Enrollment.ActualDelivery) IS NOT NULL)
        AND ((Forms.[2MonthQoL]) IS NULL)
        );
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you add extra condition to the "`where`" ?

Comment: add daysoverdue>0 to your where actually you need the formula so it's DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())>0

Answer (score 1):

You can add the condition to the `where` clause:

```
WHERE Enrollment.ActualDelivery) IS NOT NULL AND
      Forms.[2MonthQoL]) IS NULL AND
      DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE()) >= 0
```

This would be more naturally written as:

```
WHERE Enrollment.ActualDelivery) IS NOT NULL AND
      Forms.[2MonthQoL]) IS NULL AND
      [Due] <= DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `ABS()` to get the absolute value of a number like:

```
SELECT Enrollment.Participant_ID
    ,Enrollment.Site
    ,Enrollment.ActualDelivery
    ,Forms.[2MonthQoL]
    ,[Enrollment].[ActualDelivery] + 70 AS Due
    ,ABS(DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())) AS DaysOverdue
FROM Enrollment
LEFT JOIN Forms ON Enrollment.Participant_ID = Forms.Participant_IDFK
WHERE (
        ((Enrollment.ActualDelivery) IS NOT NULL)
        AND ((Forms.[2MonthQoL]) IS NULL)
        );
```

If you just want those negatives to be NULL you can use an `IIF()`:

```
SELECT Enrollment.Participant_ID
    ,Enrollment.Site
    ,Enrollment.ActualDelivery
    ,Forms.[2MonthQoL]
    ,[Enrollment].[ActualDelivery] + 70 AS Due
    ,IIF((DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())<0, NULL, (DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())) AS DaysOverdue
FROM Enrollment
LEFT JOIN Forms ON Enrollment.Participant_ID = Forms.Participant_IDFK
WHERE (
        ((Enrollment.ActualDelivery) IS NOT NULL)
        AND ((Forms.[2MonthQoL]) IS NULL)
        );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the input so far. The recommend solutions do not work as expected. When put in IIF((DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())<0 or Daysoverdue>o the column returns returns 0 or -1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the input so far. The recommend solutions do not work as expected. When put in IIF((DateDiff("d", [Due], DATE ())<0 or Daysoverdue>o the column returns returns 0 or -1. Please help